# MySQL date just doesn't want to be inserted

Tags: mysql, date

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE `bans` (  
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  
    `ip` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
    `uid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, 
    `end` date NOT NULL,  
    `type` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,  
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) 
ENGINE=InnoDB 
AUTO_INCREMENT=17 
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Where I try to insert the following data

```
INSERT INTO `bans` 
VALUES (NULL,INET_ATON('0.0.0.2'),9,2013-6-17,1)
```

A record is being created but the date is always 0000-00-00 no matter what date I supply. Please help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put your date in quotes:

```
INSERT INTO `bans` 
VALUES (NULL,INET_ATON('0.0.0.2'),9,'2013-6-17',1)
```

`2013-6-17` = `1990` which is a very small unix timestamp indeed.

Comment: Not sure about the math, but +1 anyway.